# How to download the previous releases of the opendistro elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch-opendistro

I have opendistro elasticsearch 1.10.1 running in my machine. I want to try the same version of kibana. But from the opendistro website, only the latest version is available for download. I am unable to download the previous releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised this issue with the OpenDistro team on their Github page. The answer is, for now, there is no page available to download the earlier releases directly from the site. Instead, they have provided a link where we can mention the required version and download it.

Refer to the link for the answer,
https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/opendistro-build/issues/665

Comment: We recently added a page for downloading the previous versions. You can use this link to download previous version - https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/previousversions/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the previous releases using this link  - https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/previousversions/